# How do i use toLower with StartsWith

Tags: c#

I need your help.
I want a user make an input to search a list of objects.
Here, the user should specify the initial letter of the object.

Now the problem, since some words are capitalized and other small I would like to regulate so that both the user input and the object from the list are always written in small.

I thought you might be able to do that with `toLower` but that does not work on the list object.
Incidentally, the list object is a string.

Is there an easy solution with the `toLower` or how can this be done best?

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first Letter");

string search = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

Console.Clear();

foreach(var erg in speichert)
{
    if (erg.B_NAME.ToLower().StartsWith(search))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("something");
    }
}
```

Comment: [StartsWith(String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_)

Comment: Check the StartsWith overloads, there is a case insensitive option [StartsWith(String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use instead the [String.StartsWith() overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_) that has a case insensitive option, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first Letter");
string search = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();
foreach(var erg in speichert)
{
    if (erg.B_NAME.StartsWith(search, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Especially for a larger amount of comparisons this saves the overhead of converting and copying each string before comparing them